# SwiftUI: updating View with changes to Core Data relationship array

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsmanagedobject, observedobject

I have a SwiftUI view where a Core Data NSManagedObject is passed in (without @FetchRequest) and where the subview needs to show the one-to-many relationship from the first entity. In this case, a `Person` is passed in, and I want to show the `Tags` associated with that Person.

```
struct CJMapsCalloutView: View {

@ObservedObject var personAddress: PersonAddress

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                    
        if let personTags = personAddress.person?.getSortedListOfAssignedTags() {
            ContactTagsList(personTags: personTags)
        }
    }
}
```

The ContactTagsList

```
struct ContactTagsList: View {

@State var personTags: [Tag]
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
        
        ForEach(personTags) { (tag: Tag) in
            ContactTag(personTag: tag)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 0).padding(.trailing, 2)
    }
}
```

When using `@State`, it displays the tags list just fine, and even changes to individual `Tags` are reflected automatically in the view as well. But any changes to the 'relationship', whether adding or removing tags from the `Person`, don't cause the view to update.

I tried using `@ObservedObject` instead of `@State` for the `var personTags`, but that gives errors at compile time:

> Property type '[Tag]' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue'
> property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'

I'm new to SwiftUI, so I'm not sure what the issue is with using @ObservedObject. And if I can't use that, what's the best way to handle this situation to get automatic updates to the relationship?

Comment: are you deleting and saving correctly?

Comment: Yes, definitely, since the changes reflect if I close the view and open I again.

Comment: 1) Instead of [Tag] keep it just Tag, and make it @ObservedObject. 2) Loop over tags in CJMapsCalloutView, and pass each tag to childView, instead of looping in childView. Give it a try.